# Proper ln() with variable exponents in a limit: $L=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2^n}{5\cdot 3^{(n+1)}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Here's my initial equation:

$$L\hspace{1em}=\hspace{1em}\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2^n}{5\cdot 3^{(n\:+\:1)}}$$

My evaluation:

\begin{align}
e^\left(\ln(L)\right)\hspace{1em}&=\hspace{1em}\lim_{n\to\infty} e^\left(\ln\left(\frac{2^n}{5\cdot 3^{(n\:+\:1)}}\right)\right) \tag{1}\\[1em]
&=\hspace{1em}\lim_{n\to\infty} e^{\left(\ln(2^n)\:-\:\ln(5\cdot3^{(n\:+\:1)}\right)} \tag{2}\\[1em]
&=\hspace{1em}\lim_{n\to\infty} e^{\left(\ln(2^n)\:-\:(\ln(5)\:+\:\ln\left(3^{(n\:+\:1)}\right)\right)} \tag{3}\\[1em]
&=\hspace{1em}\lim_{n\to\infty} e^{\left(n\cdot\ln(2)\:-\:(\ln(5)\:+\:(n\:+\:1)\cdot\ln(3))\right)} \tag{4}\\[1em]
&=\hspace{1em}\lim_{n\to\infty} e^{\left(n\cdot\ln(2)\:-\:\ln(5)\:-\:(n\:+\:1)\cdot\ln(3)\right)} \tag{5}\\[1em]
&=\hspace{1em}\lim_{n\to\infty} e^{\left(n\cdot\ln(2)\:-\:\ln(5)\:-\:(n\cdot\ln(3)\:+\:\ln(3))\right)} \tag{6}\\[1em]
&=\hspace{1em}\lim_{n\to\infty} e^{\left(n\cdot\ln(2)\:-\:\ln(5)\:-\:n\cdot\ln(3)\:-\:\ln(3)\right)} \tag{7}\\[1em]
&=\hspace{1em}\lim_{n\to\infty} e^{\left(n\cdot\ln(2)\:-\:n\cdot\ln(3)\:-\:\ln(5)\:-\:\ln(3)\right)} \tag{8}\\[1em]
&=\hspace{1em}\lim_{n\to\infty} e^{\left(n\cdot(\ln(2)\:-\:\ln(3))\:-\:\ln(5)\:-\:\ln(3)\right)} \tag{9}\\[1em]
&=\hspace{1em}\lim_{n\to\infty} e^{\left(n\cdot(\ln(2)\:-\:\ln(3))\:+\:\ln\left(5^{-1}\right)\:+\:\ln\left(3^{-1}\right)\right)} \tag{10}\\[1em]
&=\hspace{1em}\lim_{n\to\infty} e^{\left(n\cdot(\ln(2)\:-\:\ln(3))\:+\:\ln\left(5^{-1}\cdot3^{-1}\right)\right)} \tag{11}\\[1em]
&=\hspace{1em}\lim_{n\to\infty} e^{\left(n\cdot(\ln(2)\:-\:\ln(3))\:+\:\ln\left(15^{-1}\right)\right)} \tag{12}\\[1em]
&=\hspace{1em}\lim_{n\to\infty} e^{\left(n\cdot(\ln(2)\:-\:\ln(3))\:+\:\ln\left(\frac{1}{15}\right)\right)} \tag{13}\\[1em]
&=\hspace{1em}\lim_{n\to\infty} e^{\left(n\cdot(\ln(2)\:-\:\ln(3))\right)}\cdot e^{\left(\ln\left(\frac{1}{15}\right)\right)} \tag{14}\\[1em]
&=\hspace{1em}\lim_{n\to\infty} e^{\left(n\cdot(\ln(2)\:-\:\ln(3))\right)}\cdot \frac{1}{15} \tag{15}\\[1em]
&=\hspace{1em}\lim_{n\to\infty} e^{\left(n\cdot(-)\right)}\cdot \frac{1}{15} \tag{16}\\[1em]
&=\hspace{1em}e^{\left(\infty\cdot(-)\right)}\cdot \frac{1}{15} \tag{17}\\[1em]
&=\hspace{1em}e^{\left(-\infty\right)}\cdot \frac{1}{15} \tag{18}\\[1em]
&=\hspace{1em}0\cdot \frac{1}{15} \tag{19}\\[1em]
L\hspace{1em}&=\hspace{1em}0 \tag{20}
\end{align}

So my question, trivial as it may be, is at my step 16.

Is it proper to merely simplify the $\ln()$ subtraction to a mere "-", or would it be more proper to show the $\ln()$ subtraction result in it's approximate form of: -0.40546510?

Thanks!

Comment: I think "-" is acceptable, since any negative value will lead to the same result.

Comment: I don't like $\lim_{n\to\infty} e^{n(-)} = e^{\infty\cdot(-)}$. You can't treat infinity as a number, in general, so you have to be careful. In particular, $\infty\cdot(-)$ is nonsense not because of the $(-)$, which we can take as some $C<0$, but because $\infty$ is not a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the start you could have written $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2^n}{5\cdot 3^{(n\:+\:1)}} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac 1{15}\cdot \left(\frac 23\right)^n$$

which would have greatly simplified calculating the limit.

---

Regarding your work: Note that $$e^{n(\ln(2)- \ln 3)}\cdot \frac 1{15} = e^{n\ln(2/3)} \cdot \frac 1{15}=e^{\ln\left(\left(\frac 23\right)^n\right)}\cdot \frac 1{15} = \frac{1}{15}\left(\frac 23\right)^n$$

Nothing too complicated there.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: informally, the minus sign is acceptable.

Maybe you're interested in another way of solving this limit, which is way shorter:

Write

$$\frac{2^n}{5\cdot3^{n+1}}=\frac{1}{15}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n$$ which obviously goes to $0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, $$\frac{2^n}{5\cdot 3^{n+1}} = \frac{2^{n+1}}{2 \cdot 5 \cdot 3^{n+1}} \\ = \frac{1}{10}\cdot \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{n+1}$$